How to reconcile hereditary varna vs. the limits of Sabda Pramana?
DISCLAIMER

This question deals specifically with the belief that one's varna depends on the family into which one is born. For those that believe varna is based only on actions and qualities, this question does not apply. For those that believe varna is determined at birth, but is not necessarily linked to lineage, this question does not apply.

People like the Sankaracharya of Puri, and many others, hold the following beliefs:

Source - Being born into a Brahmin family is a requirement to be a Brahmin. Anyone not born to a Brahmin family is never a Brahmin by varna.
Source - The different varnas have different innate qualities.

Put together, the above would imply that the family you're born into also determines what innate qualities you have. But pratyaksha (perception) tells us that in the modern day, your surname or bloodline is not a necessary factor for you to have qualities of sattva, rajas, or tamas.
Given this apparent contradiction in the proposition of scripture vs. what we can know to be true in the real world, are we not called to re-interpret the scripture to arrive at a different meaning? Indeed, why did we allow scripture to make claims about the material world in the first place, when that seems to fall in the purview of what we can otherwise measure and ascertain?

"Source - Being born into a Brahmin family is a requirement to be a Brahmin. Anyone not born to a Brahmin family is never a Brahmin by varna." This also means that being born into a brahmin family does not make one a respectable brahmin. This agrees with your observation in the first paragraph.

"Source - Being born into a Brahmin family is a requirement to be a Brahmin. Anyone not born to a Brahmin family is never a Brahmin by varna."  Scriptures give a handful of exceptions. Satyakama (son of Jabala in the Chandogya Upanishad) was granted brahminhood due to his truthfulness

"Given this apparent contradiction in the proposition of scripture vs. what we can know to be true in the real world, are we not called to re-interpret the scripture to arrive at a different meaning?" No need to reinterpret scriptures. Just read alot of scriptures and have a holistic and comprehensive understanding of sanatan dharma and its nuances.

"Source - The different varnas have different innate qualities." On average this is true, but there are exceptions. Lord Shri Ramachandra beheaded the sudra Sambhuka for practicing sadhana but was good friends with the Nishada Guha. Selfless devotion to Parabrahman has no varna restrictions but varna restrictions apply once sadhana becomes selfish and non-devotional. Hence Lord Rama punished Sambhuka but embraced Guha.

Read Chanakya Niti. In one statement Pandit Shri Chanakya mentioned that even if a lowly born man is a  true knower of scripture, he is worshiped by the devatas. The varna of that man does not necessarily change, but his respectability does. I think there are other scriptural verses that reveal Sudras are not entitled to listening to the Vedas. For such verses, we note that the Vedas are divided into two sections: Karma kandha (rituals) and Jnana kandha (knowledge on Parabrahman). Therefore such verses can mean Sudras are not entitles to the Karma kandha but they can be entitled to  Jnana

"Therefore such verses can mean Sudras are not entitles to the Karma kandha but they can be entitled to Jnana." In the Bhagavad Gita, Lord Shriman Narayana mentions that Sudras can be eligible to study the Gita.

You can read the lives and teachings of Shri Ramanuja and Shri Madhvacharya, both of whom were staunch believers in the varnashrama dharma and swa-dharma (caste-based duties). If all varnas were firmly devoted to the Parabrahman while simultaneously following their swa-dharma faithfully, Vedic culture would thrive and no higher varna member would look down upon a lower varna member and no lower varna member would resent a higher varna member because such impure feelings would not exist in pure minds.

Those who are truely devoted to the Parabrahman do not worry about changing varnas. They faithfully follow their swa-dharma and depend solely on the Parabrahman to help them cope with life's miseries and abuses -- this, in my humble opinion, is a main teaching of the Bhagavata Gita. Follow your duty given to you by God, do not copy someone else's duties, and have staunch devotion towards Him. If you do these, you will be fine.

@23315 Thanks for your responses Debbie. I am more so interested in how we determine what the "prescribed duties" are in the first place. In short, can we accept that to be a Brahmin one must be part of a Brahmin family, when such a belief leads to a contradiction with perception/logic?

To be Brahmin-natured one need not be part of a brahmin family.  To be eligible for moksha, one need not be born into a brahmin family. To perform the prescribed duties unique to a brahmin (purohit and teachers of Vedas to the disciples while living the life of a householder) one must be born into a brahmin family; however just because one is born to a brahmin family does not mean he can perform these duties. He needs to have or develop good qualities as a child. A bad natured brahmin should, in my opinion, should be disqualified from teaching the Vedas.

@23315 (Debbie), this part is what I am having issue with. [ To perform the prescribed duties unique to a brahmin (purohit and teachers of Vedas to the disciples while living the life of a householder) one must be born into a brahmin family ] Because "Brahmin" is defined in the Gita as someone with certain innate qualities. And we know those innate qualities appear in all kinds of different families. So the scriptural assertion that this /only/ appears in certain families would run contrary to pratyaksha (perception).

@23315 (Debbie), the underlying difficulty I am having with this is that this belief (varna is decided by family) divides human beings by genetics. Most DharmaShastras that speak on varnas openly classify Brahmins as the topmost, and Shudras as people created only to serve the others three. The assertion that this classification is decided by blood and mandated by God feels incredibly off-putting in my admittedly liberalized mind. ---- Ultimately I am glad that not all Hindus believe in varna-by-heredity. But those that do, always end up sounding like "master race" people to my ears.

I understand your concern. My advise to you would be to focus on the Vedanta and selfless devotion to Parabrahman -- there is no varna restriction for this. Don't focus too much on the varna system if that bothers you. If anyone says you will incur sin for not following your swa-dharma, then you can point out the following verse which states that all such sins will be annulled if devotion is genuine:  sarva-dharmān parityajya mām ekaṁ śharaṇaṁ vraja
ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo mokṣhayiṣhyāmi mā śhuchaḥ (Gita 18.66)
